# Terminal FTP client with progress bar

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, ftp

I'm SSHing to a headless Ubuntu box and sometimes need to upload files from that box via FTP. The built-in FTP client does not show the progress of my upload (or at least I don't know how to view it). I just see this during the operation (which could take up to an hour):

> 150 Opening BINARY mode data
>   connection for MyFile

Are there any FTP clients which I could use in terminal and would show the progress (some kind of a progress bar or just the percentage)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could type the 'hash' command inside FTP to turn on some kind of feedback.

I always used to use `ncftp` as it gave good command line editing, history, and progress.

Comment: Excellent, **ncftp** is exactly what I was looking for. The `hash`command really just shows that _something_ is happening (prints a # sign per every block transferred) but doesn't help me understand the progress :)

Comment: That work with SSH connection?

Answer (score 5):

ncftpput is what you want. There is no better shell ftpclient :)
You will see your progress in %, uploaded bytes and remaining time.